# Excel asks to save even though I did just save

Tags: excel

I've uploaded a [video](https://youtu.be/ws0L3t5OpLE) on Youtube showing the problem (Youtube because [I can't do it on StackOverflow directly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248250/1134213)).

Any idea why I have this problem? I'm using Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2203 Build 16.0.15028.20178) 64-bit  for enterprise on Windows 11.

My add-ins: [image]

Here is a [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/4726f3233c2fa15f2177b4bed9aec58d20220414124108/f90370) to download the file.

EDITs: Safe Mode fixes the problem. De-activating my (only) add-in fixes the problem. Still not satisfied because I want to use Excel with the add-in and I don't want to launch it in safe mode everytime.

EDIT2: On my other laptop which also works on Windows 11, I do not have this problem.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya unfortunately the error persists, it only disappears temporarily in Safe Mode

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows I have both activated and I have not experienced this issue at all. Maybe they are related (for a strange reason I don't undersand). Anyways, did you do a complete uninstall and reinstall of Excel? Do you work at Mac or Windows?

Comment: I work on Windows 11. On my other laptop which also works on Windows 11, I do not have this problem. I've added this to the post (EDIT: it was already in there my bad). I know this is quite the nightmare to resolve, but this is quite annoying as I have to input a value in this Excel everyday. I did uninstall and reinstall Excel. Without the add-in, it worked but as soon as I re-added it, it stopped working.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have on both the laptops?

Comment: Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2203 Build 16.0.15028.20178) 64-bit